# How can I set large amounts of HTML code with POST variables to a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, html

```
$content = '<div id="contact" style="display:''; border-radius: 5px; padding: 20px;" class="center"><br><!--Spacing--><br><!--Spacing--></div>
<div id="contact" style="display:''; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #EBEBEB; padding: 20px;" class="center">
<form>
<center><h4><b>' . $_POST['email1'] . " " . $_POST['email2'] . '</b></h4></center>
<br><!--Spacing-->
<center>' . $_POST['email4'] . '<center>
<br><!--Spacing-->
<center>' . $_POST['email3'] . '<center>
<br><!--Spacing-->
<center>' . $_POST['email5'] . '<center>
<br><!--Spacing-->
<center><img src="rushforms/profile_images/' . $_POST['file_number'] . '.png"/></center>
<center><img src="rushforms/profile_images/' . $_POST['file_number'] . '.jpg"/></center>
<center><img src="rushforms/profile_images/' . $_POST['file_number'] . '.gif"/></center>
</form>
</div>';
```

How can I set all of this to `$content`?

I was under the impression that ' ' could be used to set html code to a variable in php.

Comment: yes that'll work, just make sure those post values are populated

Comment: why would you want to put that much html in a variable? But to answer the question: basically you need read up on escaping your `'` with `\'` ... which is why its better not to put that much html in a variable...its gonna get ugly

Comment: it would also help to be consistent. If you used `'` on the outside, use only `"` on the inside. If you used `"` on the outside, only use `'` on the inside. Then you won't need to escape with `\"` or `\'`

Answer (score 0):

It will work but when you have such content it can be easier to use [heredoc or nowdoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.types.string.php) .

It will avoid all that concatenations.